# How to plot line connecting tops of bar plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a bar plot that I want to plot a line over that connects the top of the bars to see a general trend. My code currently looks like this (note - ratio is a pandas dataframe with column data_points):

```
ratio['data_points'].plot(kind='bar')
ratio['data_points'].plot()
plt.title('')
plt.show()
```

And I get back a plot that looks like this:
[image]

I'm not sure how to alter this so that the bar plot shows properly (ie, the full bar for Week 1 and Week 4 are actually on the plot) and how to make it so that the line plot just connects the tops of the bars (the fall to 0 on week 3 is fine still - I don't need week 2 to connect to week 4 unless that's the only way to do this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

1. plot line first, with higher `zorder` than `bar`
2. plot bar in different color after, which help realign the xaxis automatically

Like this:

```
ratio.data_points.plot(zorder=5)
ratio['data_points'].plot(kind='bar', color='C2', zorder=1)
plt.title('')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]